# Struggling to code the functionality of my pagination buttons on a custom slider

Tags: javascript, css, pagination, slider

I'm creating a custom slider for a client and I've hit a bit of a plateau on it.

THE GOAL

- Create custom slider for 6 different industries.
- The slider should have forward and back buttons which slide through the different industries.
- There should be custom-styled pagination buttons which allow the user to navigate the slider to specific slides when clicked.
- The pagination should identify which slide we're currently on and highlight the appropriate pagination button.

WHAT I'VE DONE

- The slides, forward and back buttons, and pagination buttons have all been created and styled.
- The functionality of the forward and back buttons work.
- The slider identifies which slide it's on and highlights the relevant pagination button.

THE PROBLEMS I'M FACING

- I can't seem to get the pagination buttons to function on click.
- I have a styling issue on the pagination buttons where if the text is too long to fit on one line, the button vertically rises above the rest. Can't seem to work this one out. *(UPDATE: 12:29 07/03/2020 - Fixed this now. Simple enough in the end with vertical-align. Was just having a bit of a brain fart on it.)*

Other than those 2 problems, it's pretty much there.

I've created a pen for this on codepen for you guys to see: https://codepen.io/chris-jk/pen/abOVzoy

I'll paste the relevant javascript below for the navigateSlider function and for the pagination.

```
function navigateSlider() {
    slidesWrapper.style.transform = "translateX(-" + (100 * counter) + "%)";        
    paginationButtons[prevCounter].classList.remove("sel");
    paginationButtons[counter].classList.add("sel");
    //bar.style.animationDuration = '1000s';
    //restartAutomation();
    prevCounter = counter;
}

var pagination = document.getElementsByClassName("pagination")[0];
var paginationButtons = pagination.getElementsByTagName("span");
   for(var i = 0;i < len;i++) {
      var ele = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
      ele.onclick = (function(i) {
         return function() {
            counter = i;
            navigateSlider();
         }
      })(i)
      if (i === 0) {ele.className = "sel";}
      pagination.appendChild(ele);
   }
```

Any assistance appreciated!

Comment: Why should `.getElementsByTagName()` return different things (`paginationButtons[prevCounter]` but `ele.onclick = ...`)?

Comment: Which is also the source for the `TypeError: Argument 1 of Node.appendChild does not implement interface Node`